# What Arduino boards would be compatible?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am considering using an arduino over the raspberry pi for a new project. However, I am not sure what arduino I should buy so that it is compatible with the below add-on.

[image: add-on board]

Are all Arduinos compatible?

TIA.

Edit:

Link to product- https://www.adafruit.com/product/3387

My goal is to use an arduino with the above product to move a 3D model in Unity 3D.

Comment: Potentially all are compatible, but it is hard to tell as you did not include any of the technical details. Can you update your question with the technical details and or a link to the product? Compatible is a big word, there are many aspects to it including voltage, signaling and software support on your Arduino of choice.

Comment: Of course, my bad. Editing now!

Answer (score 3):

As one can see from the pinout description page (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-lsm9ds1-accelerometer-plus-gyro-plus-magnetometer-9-dof-breakout/pinouts):

[image]

So this board is literally designed to be powered by 3.3V and 5V and have compatible logic levels for both these voltage ranges, which is what every Arduino known to me and the Raspberry Pi use.

Furthermore, there is also Arduino Code (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_LSM9DS1)  which is compatible with pretty much every Arduino Core and Raspberry Pi Python code (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-lsm9ds1-accelerometer-plus-gyro-plus-magnetometer-9-dof-breakout/python-circuitpython).

So by means of voltage levels and platforms, this board is highly compatible with everything out there that is either 3.3V or 5V powered and has a SPI or I2C peripheral.

Comment: Right. Which is to say pretty much every Arduino out there. If it has hardware I2C lines, it will work with that board, whether the Arduino is 3.3V or 5V. Note that most commonly used Arduinos and their accessories are 5V, so I'd recommend going with a 5V module for compatibility with other "shields" and accessories.